# why the output of the auto variable displays something not related to type?

Tags: c++11, auto

I tried a example on Auto for variable initialization and STL in C++. For normal variable, type was printed using : `typeid(var_name).name()` to print `i (integer) / d(float) / pi(pointer)` which works fine. 
           But while working on STL,

```
`#include <iostream>
 #include <vector> 
 using namespace std;

 int main() 
 { 
    vector<string> st; 
    st.push_back("geeks");
    st.push_back("for"); 

    for (auto it = st.begin(); it != st.end(); it++) 
        cout << typeid(it).name() << "\n"; 

    return 0; 
} 
`
which gives output like,
`N9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt6vectorIS6_SaIS6_EEEE
N9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt6vectorIS6_SaIS6_EEEE`
```

and I am unable to understand the output logic behind it, can anyone explain why it is giving output like this? and thanks in advance

Comment: That's the platform-specific, mangled name of your library's `std::vector<string>::iterator`. What's wrong about it?

Comment: "can anyone explain why it is giving output like this?" - because `it` is an iterator; if you want something "s(string)", you have to pass `*it` to `typeid()`

Comment: even i gave typeid(*it) it is giving output as `NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE  `  and what it actually represents ?

Comment: "even i gave typeid(*it) it is giving output as [...]  and what it actually represents" - well... also `std::string` isn't exactly trivial: it represent a `std::string` that is a short-hand for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`

Answer (score 1):

That's the "[name mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)" version of the name of the type of `it`. `typeinfo::name()` is not required by the standard to return a name in human-readable format (a shortcoming IMHO) and GCC doesn't do so.

To get the actual, human-readable name, you need to call the [`abi::__cxa_demangle()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) function provided by GCC, but note that this is non-portable so if your project needs to work on different compilers you'll need to wrap it appropriately.

Comment: It is possible to demangle the name from the oitside. Pipe the mangled output through `c++filt` program (should come with binutils).